# What has happened to the revision history of this answer?

Tags: bug

This is rather odd. Consider [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/81441/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor/81451#81451) answer.

The current content of the answer according to `http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/answers/81451?body=true` is:

> `...<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKfk2.png"...`

**However,** the content returned from `http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/81451` tend to indicate that the latest revision changed the contents to:

> `...<img src="http://imgur.com/NIqOe.png"...`

Which source is correct?